# Single PHP page with $_GET parameters, is it bad for SEO?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, get, seo, googlebot

Suppose I have a website for a company which I want to SEO.

Think of two scenarios:

1) There is only `index.php`, and for /about /contact sections I do it like this:
`index.php?what=about` , `index.php?what=contact` etc. and I change the url using .htaccess, so the links become `www.company.com/about` , `www.company.com/contact` and every page has unique content of course.

2) Everything has their own page. i.e. :

- http

  - index.php
  - about.php
  - contact.php

I think that these two scenarios are the same, if they have the same content. I mean Google should not care about the server-end right? Or am I wrong? Please inform me before I go any further :)

Thanks !

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO, not programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both scenarios are equally good, for SEO is it's important only that you have unique URLs.
Talking about technical side, for small projects it is not crucial weather you use `index.php?what=contact` or `contact.php` so choose whatever you prefer
For bigger projects it is more practical to use first approach, where the application sends all the client requests to one page (be it index.php) and then run the query.

Comment: Yes that's what I was doing. the main page actually has static content, but since the customer's needs are dynamic, I like to handle them in content_generator.php, and call whatever $_GET variable is requested, from content generator. Thanks for your help :)